# Calling navigation controller method from background operation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, nsoperation

I'm running a background operation using NSOperation, which gets kicked off from my AppDelegate.  What I want to do is when the operation is complete, have it call a method in the RootViewController.m file.

Currently there's a property in my AppDelegate named navigationController, and I"ve been trying to set up the call like this:

AppDelegate.m:

```
GetRSSOperation *gro = [[GetRSSOperation alloc] initWithURL:rssURL target:self selector:@selector(dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData:)];
    [queue addOperation:gro];
    [gro release];
```

GetRSSOperation.m:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:alerts waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I have tried setting the target to self, self.navigationController, self.navigationController.view but none work.

I am aware that the issue might be due to my not yet having a complete understanding of the entire ios architecture, so would appreciate any pointers please.

**Adding more code to explain:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
    NSOperationQueue *queue;
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;

    NSURL *rssURL;

    // storage for the alert list from RSS feed
    NSMutableArray *alerts;     
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *alerts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *rssURL;
@property (retain) NSOperationQueue *queue;


+ (id)shared;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AlertViewController.h"
#import "RefreshTableHeader.h"
#import "GetRSSOperation.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
static AppDelegate *shared;

@synthesize window, navigationController, alerts;


- (id)init
{
    if (shared) {
        [self autorelease];
        return shared;
    }
    if (![super init]) return nil;

    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    shared = self;
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

        // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
        UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 3, 37, 37)];
        imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageview]; 
        [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        if (rssURL == nil) {
            NSString *alertAddress = @"http://www.compoundstockearnings.com/com/public/selections.cfc?method=getrss&email=";
            alertAddress = [alertAddress stringByAppendingString:cseLogin];
            alertAddress = [alertAddress stringByAppendingString:@"&password="];
            alertAddress = [alertAddress stringByAppendingString:csePass];      
            rssURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:alertAddress];
        }

        GetRSSOperation *gro = [[GetRSSOperation alloc] initWithURL:rssURL target:self selector:@selector(dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData:)];
        [queue addOperation:gro];
        [gro release];      
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

GetRSSOperation just does the rss call, puts it in memory then tries to call the main navigation controller:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:alerts waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The main navigation controller upon which I wish the thing to execute a selector, looks like this:

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet RefreshTableHeader *alertTable;

    UIImageView *imageView; 

}

@end

RootViewController.m:
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData:(NSMutableArray *)tempAlerts 
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.alerts = tempAlerts;
    reloading = NO;
    [alertTable flipImageAnimated:NO];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [alertTable setStatus:kPullToReloadStatus];
    [alertTable toggleActivityView:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [popSound play];
}
```

Obviously I've shortened it a bit but that's the core of it.  I just want the GetRSSOperation to be able to call RootViewController.m - dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData.  any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're having a bit of trouble figuring out just how to format the call to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` correctly. It's pretty simple, really.
If you would normally call the method like this:

```
[target method:alerts]
```

you format the performSelector call like this:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method:) withObject:alerts waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: Yes I understand that part, I'm actually passing the target and selector into the GetRSSOperation.  My problem is that it's not executing it, so I'm assuming my target is wrong...

Comment: Post more code then. Reduce your existing code to a test case that does nothing but illustrate the problem, but that actually does illustrate the problem.

Comment: The method `dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData:` is on RootViewController, so you need to pass an instance of that class for `target`.